# Restore heroku postgres password

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, passwords

How to recover a password for my heroku postgresql database? I used this command `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset` but can't gain access to my django admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your current credentials with `heroku pg:credentials DATABASE` or `heroku config`. You can then use the elements of the URL displayed to connect via a DB admin tool like Pgadmin. The password is the text between the : and the @.

Comment: Ok, i see the same credentials through web interface. But I can't access my db through `admin/` using them. I need to get an access to django admin page. And As far as I know it always uses registered users in db, but heroku seems to be working different.

Comment: Are you sure the django password has anything to do with your Postgres password? How about `heroku run manage.py changepassword admin`.